# Real World Gevent and Asyncio usecase

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, python-asyncio, gevent

*After reading lots of article on the web, here are my understanding of concurrent programs-*

> In python, if we have CPU bound task, then we can take advantage of
> the multiprocessing module (reason GIL). If we are doing network i/o or disk i/o
> then we can take advantage of multithreading.

**Before this, I tried to understand the basics behind this all and these are my thoughts about them-**

> Synchronous in the multithreaded environment: Tasks get executed in
> different threads but wait for any other executing tasks on any other
> thread.
>
> Asynchronous: Single-threaded: Tasks start executing without waiting
> for a different task to finish. At a given time a single task gets
> executed. Multithreaded: Tasks get executed in different threads
> without waiting for any tasks and independently finish off their
> executions.
>
> The asynchronous programming model helps us to achieve concurrency.
> The asynchronous programming model in a multi-threaded environment is
> a way to achieve parallelism.

**So my understanding boils down to threads, greenlets and coroutines run using event loop in asyncio library.**

We can achieve asyncio behavior using threads (if we leave thread os scheduling, context switch, and memory overhead) then where we can have benefits of all these 3 paradigms.

Please provide some real and production level examples with an explanation of why they are using used.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IMO the largest consideration around each is the scaling profile.  Threading and Multiprocessing scale with respect to the number of threads/processes available to your program while async can scale sub linearly for IO based workloads with respect to the number of processes available.

**Multi Threaded**

Because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) I have not seen threads used very much.  Uwsgi, celery, and other frameworks offer a thread based worker.  Some positives of threads are:

- native support
- if you know your workload is IO bound it can be less complex to use a threading model so that you share a single address space.
- Throughput scales with respect to the number of processes available

The reasons I would NOT recommend threads:

- Race conditions / thread safety

Many applications (third party modules) don't consider this and may have shared memory and open up application to race conditions. This is something to watch out for and I see frequently.

**Multi Process**

Uwsgi/Celery :) In my experiences this is the default concurrency primitive because parallelism is possible, less chance of race conditions, standard library support, and non GIL.

Pros:

- Standard library primitives

Cons:

- Process management (ie need to keep track of process health)
- Throughput scales with respect to the number of processes available

**Asyncio**

Twisted, tornado and asyncio.

This is extremely common for web or network frameworks, because most of their work is usually IO based workloads. Asynchronous IO enables a single thread to handle hundreds or thousands or tens of thousands or even a million :) connections at a single time. Compare this to a pre-fork or process based model which would need a process available for each concurrent request.

The major downside of this, is that since asynchronous IO frameworks are usually single threaded, any CPU bound workloads will block forward progress of the event loop, which is a super common operational problem for runtimes like node/v8.